# Can we mix dual-rank and single-rank DDR4 RAMs

Tags: memory, ddr

I currently have a [HyperX HX421C14FB2/8](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104673) 8GB DDR4 RAM. I want to upgrade my system to have 16 GB RAM. I already have bought the [HyperX HX421C14FB/8](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820104530) 8GB DDR4 RAM.

I understand that my current RAM is a single-rank RAM and my new one is dual-ranked RAM. My question is can I plugin the new RAM into my MOBO and expect everything to work harmoniously?

My MOBO is a MSI Gaming Z170A M5.

Comment: I tried it and it works without hassles.

Answer (score 2):

Not if you keep it in the same channel setup. if it's in a different channel set up then it will work as long as the other 2 RAMs are the same. You can't interchange the pairs unfortunately or not you'll get weird hiccups & blue screens (I tried). But with RAM you never know. It may work, it just significantly lowers the chance of it working if you mix different types.