# Does having a Single rank and a Dual rank memory module cause problems?

Tags: memory

In my concrete case, I'd like to have this:

https://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX421C14FB2_8.pdf

with this:

https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/HX421C14FB_8.pdf

Comment: It's not ideal, but you can have them on separated dual(triple, quad) channel. If they are in the same channel it may cause some troubles, system inestability, etc.

Comment: So with this CPU it's possible to use them with dual channel and without troubles? 
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88184/intel-core-i5-6500-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html 
What do I gain if I just buy a brand new single ranked kit or a brand new dual rank kit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we mix dual-rank and single-rank DDR4 RAMs](https://superuser.com/questions/1153164/can-we-mix-dual-rank-and-single-rank-ddr4-rams)

Comment: Single ranked matched memory performs slightly better. Dual bank, and quad bank, memory is slightly slower since only one bank can be accessed at any given moment, and there's a minor performance hit in switching banks. Minor.